# Can I deploy Spinnaker on IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, spinnaker

I wonder if I can deploy Spinnaker (http://spinnaker.io) to a Virtual Machine on IBM Bluemix. If yes, how? Is there any instruction available?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Foundry support (which is what IBM Bluemix is based upon) is available.

If you visit http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/target-deployment-setup#section-cloud-foundry-platform-setup, you'll how to deploy Spinnaker into any Cloud Foundry compliant instance.

NOTE: As all the outstanding issues previously posted have been addressed, I updated this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a docker compose configuration. This might be more straightforward - https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/tree/master/experimental/docker-compose